# Failing tests because of the daylight saving time change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have tests where Im using `getByText` function in `react-testing-library`.
Im looking for element in DOM that has value `"10-10-2020 12:00"`.
But after daylight saving time change, all my tests have failed because due to the change, the display text has changed to `"10-10-2020 13:00"` (one hour forwards) and now Im not able to get those elements. I will have to update my tests, but they will obviously fail once again when the time is changed in winter.

It happens because e.g. `new Date('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')` returns `01 01 2020 01:00:00` instead of `01 01 2020 00:00:00` because of the timezones.

Is there any workaround or fix to make my tests resistant to daylight saving time change and timezones?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Setting the hardcoded](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestsetsystemtimenow-number--date) date and time for `jest` should help:

```
jest.useFakeTimers('modern')

beforeEach(() => {
  const hardcodedDate = new Date('2022-03-20T12:00:00Z')
  jest.setSystemTime(hardcodedDate.getTime())
})
```

It means in your tests you will always have the same system time, which will help with daylight saving time change (or any time change)

UPD: to see the date in the tests before the daylight saving you should change the hardcoded day before it started (for example in the UK it's 27 March)

Comment: Thanks, but it still returns one hour forwards time... :(

Comment: updated the answer. You should change the hardcoded date

Comment: Unfortunately still no progress

Comment: have you tried to set a timezone when you run the jest, like `TZ=UTC jest`?

Comment: Yes that was the issue unfortunately... thanks!